# creating VerticalRuler and add Information

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm pretty new to Eclipse plugins and I want to create a VerticalRuler, I found this picture of Subeclipse which inspired me to add information to a specific code line.
[image: diff of subeclipse]
Right now I have no Clue where I would start adding a column like that. 
My first try was to create a column within my editor-plugin, but nothing happened. I'm happy about every hint that helps me start.
cheers

```
CompositeRuler ruler2;    
ruler2= new CompositeRuler();
ruler2.addDecorator(0, new AnnotationRulerColumn(100));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but if you are creating a new editor, you can overwrite
the `createVerticalRuler(...)` method. There is also an extension point for ruler Columns. See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_rulerColumns.html).

Comment: thx, overwriting sounds good. Does the function belong to SourceViewerConfiguration and is there a chance to look at the original implantation that I’m going to override?