# Eclipse editor: show markers on custom column of vertical ruler

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I asked a [question before about VerticalRulers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992863/creating-verticalruler-and-add-information), with this hint I added a second Column to the VerticalRuler and tried to add a Marker to it, but the Marker always appears on the standard Column, but not on mine. I added a second line number column to illustrate my problem. How do I change this behavior? Thanks for any help.

```
@Override
protected IVerticalRuler createVerticalRuler(){
    IVerticalRuler ruler =  super.createVerticalRuler();
    ruler2 = (CompositeRuler) ruler;
    column1 = new AnnotationRulerColumn(100);
    ruler2.addDecorator(0, column1);
    ruler2.addDecorator(2, createLineNumberRulerColumn());
    column1.addAnnotationType("MARKER");
    return ruler;
}
public String check_line(){
    IEditorPart editor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
    IFileEditorInput input = (IFileEditorInput)editor.getEditorInput() ;
    IFile file = input.getFile();
    IResource res = (IResource) file;
    try{
        IMarker m = res.createMarker(IMarker.MARKER);
        m.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER,2);
        m.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "lala");
        m.setAttribute(IMarker.TEXT, "test");
        m.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        m.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_INFO);
    } catch (CoreException e) { ... }
    return "marker created";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Let me know, if my answer doesn't help you or you still have problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use a different constructor for AnnotationRulerColumn:

```
AnnotationRulerColumn(int width, IAnnotationAccess annotationAccess)
```

You can use `DefaultMarkerAnnotationAccess` for the argument `IAnnotationAccess`:

```
protected IVerticalRuler createVerticalRuler(){
    IVerticalRuler ruler =  super.createVerticalRuler();
    CompositeRuler ruler2 = (CompositeRuler) ruler;
    column1 = new AnnotationRulerColumn(100, new DefaultMarkerAnnotationAccess());
    ruler2.addDecorator(0, column1);
    ruler2.addDecorator(2, createLineNumberRulerColumn());
    column1.addAnnotationType("MARKER");
    return ruler;
}
```

I assume you have defined an annotation type with the name "MARKER" for your marker.
If not, make sure to use the name of an annotation type, NOT marker type, for `column1.addAnnotationType("MARKER");`. You can define your own annotation type and map it to a marker type with the extension point [Annotation Types](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors_annotationTypes.html).

Your marker/annotation should then show up on your own vertical ruler.

Comment: Sorry for replying that late, but I was just to frustrated so I did different work last 2 weeks. Today I tried again and I’m happy that it works with the DefaultMarkerAnnotationAccess. The Problem now is, that it creates myMarker twice in the new Column and in the original one.

Comment: The problem was the annotation type myMarker inherited from the super clase "org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.warning" which made the marker appear in the standart column in addition