# Multiple decorator columns in Eclipse text editor

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints, multiple-columns, text-editor

Is there a way to add more than one column for decorators in an Eclipse editor.
For example, a breakpoint and a search arrow on the same line dosen't play nice with each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can [add new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082933/eclipse-editor-show-markers-on-custom-column-of-vertical-ruler) there using the [extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_rulerColumns.html), assuming you are an eclipse plugin developer.

You cannot change this as an eclipse user, however.

Comment: I was looking for it as a user. But maybe I can add the feature to the debug plugin :)